# Pressure vs Scuba diver

Tags: pressure

If a scuba diver dives into a depth of 10 metres, then he will face a pressure of 2 atm on every square metre of his body...if he takes pressurized air...this supports his lungs from being squeezed...but how about the blood pressure (roughly 1 atm)? How is he going to keep him alive? It seems he needs a space suit to survive..but we know the mighty diver doesnt need it..SO WHAT HAPPENS 10 METRES BELOW SEA LEVEL WITH THE SCUBA DIVER?

Comment: liquids and solids do not compress  noticeably.

Comment: Most of you is water, yet the ocean water doesn’t seem to mind. And your air spaces (lungs) are filled with air at the current ambient pressure by the regulator.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about physics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "absolute" pressure of the fluid blood in a scuba diver's blood vessels will rise to the ambient pressure level under water. As the heart beats the pressure in any part of the circulatory system will rise and fall leading to the flow of blood throughout the body. The fluctuations in pressure due to the beating of the heart will be small pressure fluctuations compared to the absolute pressure but this is no consequence because pressure differentials are all that is required for blood flow.

Answer (score 0):

The ambient pressure is transmitted through the tissues of the body and into the blood.. A scuba regulator maintains that pressure in the lungs. The heart generates extra pressure to maintain circulation. A diver needs to be free of congestion so that he can equalize the pressure behind the ear drum and in the sinuses.

Comment: Do you have a reference for the claim that the heart "generates" extra pressure to maintain circulation? Once the body is entirely immersed, I don't see why the heart would need to generate anything more than the standard gauge pressure of about a dozen kPa to pump blood through the body. Or do you mean simply that the circulatory system operates fine at a higher absolute pressure, e.g., 2 atm + standard blood pressure instead of 1 atm + standard blood pressure?

Comment: The circulatory system operates fine at a higher absolute pressure.  You do have to worry about extra gasses being dissolved in the blood. Both oxygen and nitrogen become toxic at high pressures and they can form bubbles if the pressure is released too fast.